# How to resolve error with Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I am using Windows 7 x32bit and Android Studio v0.8.6 and after installation I got some error with gradle .

```
             Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
             This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
             For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
             Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at
             http://gradle.org/docs/1.12/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
             Please read below process output to find out more:
                     -----------------------


             Error occurred during initialization of VM
             Could not reserve enough space for object heap
             Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
             Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Comment: Sorry I am new for Android Studio so How can I resolved This Problem..?

Comment: shut things down in the background to have more RAM? Maybe increase virtual memory size. Run Android Studio as admin. You can try many things.

Comment: I Used 4 GB RAM and I think so its sufficient for Android .

Comment: 4 GB isn't nearly enough RAM for Android Studio; Gradle itself takes 1 GB. 8 GB is probably the bare minimum, and it won't work well with that little; 16 GB is more reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

### Reducing android studio memory usage: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82894#c3

Edit studio.exe.vmoptions or studio64.exe.vmoptions in your android studio installation directory, and edit the Xms, Xmx, MaxPermSize options.

### Reducing gradle memory usage: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82894#c1

> set vmoptions for gradle in gradle.properties file. I set Xmx to 256m
>   and MaxPermSize to 128m.

---

However, this will probably slow down your android studio and/or gradle build process. If you can do it, upgrade your memory to 8 GB **AND** upgrade your OS to 64-bit.